# how to fix error #1054 unknown column in field

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

This is my table.

```
create table Property(
p_id int(4) null primary key,
p_address varchar(120) not null,
c_id int(4) not null,
foreign key (c_id) references customer (c_id)
);


insert into Property values
('2001','Elm_House_11_Short_Lane_Hertfordshire_H5_667',’3001’);

insert into Property values 
('2002','Jainlight_House_Apple_Lane_Kent_K7_988',’3002’);

insert into Property values
('2003','Excelsior_House_23_Oracle_Centre_Reading',’3003’);

insert into Property values ('2004','27_Wroxton_Road_London_SE15',’3004’);
```

I'm keep getting an unknown column error when entering this data.

Comment: You're using incorrect quoting around your `c_id` data: you're using a right quotation mark when you should actually be using an apostrophe. Note that you don't actually need to quote integers anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

remove the quotes and backticks when you insert `int` values:

```
insert into Property values
(2001,'Elm_House_11_Short_Lane_Hertfordshire_H5_667',3001);

insert into Property values 
(2002,'Jainlight_House_Apple_Lane_Kent_K7_988',3002);

insert into Property values
(2003,'Excelsior_House_23_Oracle_Centre_Reading',3003);

insert into Property values (2004,'27_Wroxton_Road_London_SE15',3004);
```

Quotes are only needed, when you working with `char` fields and backticks are escape characters for table or column names.

Comment: thanks guys my file opened with Microsoft word it changed my character configurations......would keep an i eye out for those.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error exporting from MariaDb and then importing into MySql. It concerned a field that I had recently added and for which I hadn't added values yet - so in all records this field was empty. When I added a few values for this field the error disappeared.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can´t ask another thing, even if it is related, in the answer section. Please, provide a correct answer or use Ask Question button for asking another one. If you have enough reputation, you could add a comment as well.

Comment: @GileadKenzo: if didn't ask a question. I provided an alternative answer that may be relevant for other people experiencing the same error.

Comment: Hi @user2587656. If you think this could be interested, you could ask a question and reply it or, maybe, you could expand your experience and redact a documentation. Your answer didn´t reply the original answer and could derivate in another thread of comments.