# mysql error code 1054 not sure what it means

Tags: mysql

I am getting the error code 1054 Unknown column 'interlake' in 'field list'

```
drop table if exists `Boats`;
create table `Boats` (
`bid` int(11) not null,
`bname` varchar(45) default null,
`color` varchar(15) default null,
 primary key (`bid`)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=latin1;

alter table `Boats` disable keys;
insert into `Boats` values
(101,`Interlake`,`blue`),(102,`Interlake`,`red`),(103,`Clipper`,`green`),(104,`Marine`,`red`);
alter table `Boats` enable keys;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix error #1054 unknown column in field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059779/how-to-fix-error-1054-unknown-column-in-field)

Comment: I don't have quotes or back ticks on my ints

Comment: back ticks ` are usualy used to signify column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes instead of back ticks

```
INSERT INTO `Boats`
(`bid`, `bname`, `color`) 
VALUES  
(101,"Interlake","blue"),
(102,"Interlake","red"),
(103,"Clipper","green"),
(104,"Marine","red");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing back-ticks and using  apostrophe ??

```
insert into `Boats` values
(101, 'Interlake', 'blue'),(102, 'Interlake', 'red'),(103, 'Clipper', 'green'),(104, 'Marine', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "values" and use quotes('' or "") instead of back ticks(``).

Try this

```
drop table if exists `Boats`;
create table `Boats` (
`bid` int(11) not null,
`bname` varchar(45) default null,
`color` varchar(15) default null,
 primary key (`bid`)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `Boats` disable KEYS ;

INSERT INTO Boats
    ( bid, bname, color)
VALUES
    ( 101, 'Interlake', 'blue'),
    ( 102, 'Interlake', 'blue'),
    ( 103, 'Interlake', 'blue');


ALTER TABLE `Boats` enable KEYS ;
```